# Is Paley-13 a graceful graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

The 13-node [Paley graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PaleyGraph.html) has vertices 1 to 13 that are connected by an edge when their difference is one of the values $(1,3,4,9,10,12)$.

Is Paley-13 a [graceful graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246000/graceful-graphs-with-valence-k)? Can the 13 vertices be labeled with values from 0 to 39 so that the edges have differences 1 to 39?

Paley-13 is also a [toroidal graph](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SexticToroidalGraphs/), if that helps. Here's a graceful labeling for the $9_{123}$ circulant graph.

[image: graceful toroidal]

Similarly, is the [Shrikhande Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ShrikhandeGraph.html) graceful?

Comment: Is Paley 9 known not to be graceful?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi The Paley 9 graph is also the 3x3 rook graph. It is not graceful. See this other question by Ed Pegg for an explanation: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3262295/420432

Comment: @nickgard Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both the Paley-13 graph and the Shrikhande graph are graceful.

---

The following is a graceful labeling for the Paley-13 graph:

$0,1,5,39,23,34,13,3,21,7,38,33,24$

For verification, here are the absolute differences at distance $1,3$ and $4$, cycling as necessary, demonstrating that all differences $1$ to $39$ appear once:

$1,4,34,16,11,21,10,18,14,31,5,9,24$
$39,22,29,26,20,13,6,35,12,17,38,32,19$
$23,33,8,36,2,27,25,30,3,7,37,28,15$

[image: Paley 13 graph graceful labelling]

---

Shrikhande graph:
[image: Shrikhande graph graceful labelling]

---

Both labelings were found using a depth first search with backtracking, written in C.

Searches were stopped when a solution was found, so it's not  known whether other graceful labelings are possible.

Edit: I found a second graceful labeling for the Shrikhande graph:
$0,1,6,39,2,47,32,14,46,12,5,8,29,42,28,48$.

Comment: What is the edge list for it?

Comment: The first list is given as the cyclical vertices. Each label is connected to the ones at distance $1,3,4,9,10$ and $12$ steps further round in the cycle.

Comment: Wow!  How did you find this?

Comment: A depth first search of the possible vertex values. I can limit the search space a little because $0$ and $39$ must be connected. Backtrack as soon as a known edge value is not unique. Fortunately it didn't need to search far. The search started at $0-1-3\dots$ and the first solution was at $0-1-5\dots$ I'm checking the Shrikhande Graph now, but that's much harder.

Comment: You should submit a paper to a journal (that does covers) with the title "Paley-13 is Graceful."  Just your name and a picture.

Comment: The Shrikhande graph embedding is incredible.  Definitely worth a super-short paper somewhere.