# Minimal Rook Difference Grids

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

In the below grid all 18 orthogonal differences are distinct, with a difference of 18 missing.

[image: Rook 3x3 difference grid]

Could the highest number be 18?  The resulting graph would have valence 4, making it an Eulerian [Graceful graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GracefulGraph.html) with edges(mod 4)=2.  Rosa (1967) proved Eulerian Graceful graphs must have edges(mod 4)=0 or 3, so 18 is impossible.

Thus the minimal $3\times3$ rook difference grid has $rdg(3,3)=19$.

For $rdg(1,n)$ see [Golomb Ruler](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GolombRuler.html).

$rdg(2,3)=9$ and $rdg(2,4)=16$, as shown below.

[image: rook difference grids 2x3 and 2x4]

What are values for larger grids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a depth first search written in C to find the following:

$rdg(3,4)=30$, so the $3\times4$ rook graph is graceful.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   0 & 1 & 9 & 30 \\ 
   \hline
   16 & 29 & 2 & 19 \\
   \hline
   22 & 3 & 27 & 7 \\
   \hline
\end{array}

$rdg(4,4)=48$, so the $4\times4$ rook graph is also graceful.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   0 & 1 & 23 & 47 \\ 
   \hline
   19 & 44 & 9 & 2 \\
   \hline
   37 & 42 & 3 & 11 \\
   \hline
   48 & 4 & 36 & 32 \\
   \hline
\end{array}

$rdg(3,5)=46$. This is not graceful. Like the $3\times3$, Rosa (1967) shows this is the minimum possible.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   0 & 1 & 10 & 26 & 46 \\ 
   \hline
   23 & 45 & 37 & 5 & 8 \\
   \hline
   42 & 14 & 44 & 38 & 3\\
   \hline
\end{array}

[Misha Lavrov's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3262356/420432), gives a graceful labeling of the $2\times5$ rook graph, but larger $2\times n$ rook graphs cease being graceful:

$rdg(2,6)=38$. The $2\times6$ rook graph has $36$ edges.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   0 & 1 & 10 & 16 & 34 & 38 \\ 
   \hline
   35 & 32 & 24 & 37 & 5 & 12\\
   \hline
\end{array}

$rdg(2,7)=53$. The $2\times7$ rook graph has $49$ edges.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   0 & 6 & 16 & 24 & 38 & 41 & 53 \\ 
   \hline
   31 & 52 & 3 & 51 & 12 & 8 & 1 \\
   \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Wow, nice finds!  Can you also extend this to Queen graphs?

Comment: In theory, yes. It's just a matter of specifying the edge connections. In practice, maybe not. A $4\times4$ queen graph has $76$ edges, compared to $48$ for the rook graph, and the queen graph lacks the regularity of the rook graph. The search space increases significantly as the complexity of the graph increases, so there's no guarantee that a solution can be found in a reasonable amount of time. Other search methods are possible, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a graceful labeling of the $2\times 5$ grid, so $rdg(2,5)=25$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   0 & 6 & 7 & 21 & 25 \\ 
   \hline
   24 & 22 & 19 & 11 & 2 \\
   \hline
\end{array}

I put together a simulated annealing setup for graceful-labeling type problems after your previous question, and I'll try it at some larger grids next to see if I get anywhere.

For the $3\times 4$ grid, the following labeling proves $rdg(3,4) \in \{30,31\}$ but doesn't quite settle the question:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   0 & 3 & 14 & 22 \\ 
   \hline
   27 & 9 & 4 & 29 \\
   \hline
   31 & 18 & 30 & 1 \\
   \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Just found that solution slightly later than you did, and proved it's unique ignoring row/column permutations and the 25-% complement.

Answer (score 2):

I found a new optimal solution for the $3 \times 5$ rook graph:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   5 & 46 & 45 & 28 & 0  \\ 
   \hline
   31 & 7 & 1 & 44 & 11  \\
   \hline
   40 & 21 & 13 & 6 & 42  \\
   \hline
\end{array}

Also I investigated the queen graph.

$qdg(2,2)=6$, so the $2 \times 2$ queen graph is graceful:
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
   \hline
   6 & 5 \\ 
   \hline
   2 & 0 \\
   \hline
\end{array}

$qdg(2,3)=13$, so the $2 \times 3$ queen graph is graceful:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   0 & 13 & 6 \\ 
   \hline
   10 & 2 & 1 \\
   \hline
\end{array}

$qdg(2,4)=22$, so the $2 \times 4$ queen graph is graceful:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   1 & 13 & 22 & 0 \\ 
   \hline
   21 & 3 & 6 & 17 \\
   \hline
\end{array}

$qdg(2,5) \leq 34$. The $2 \times 5$ queen graph has 33 edges:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   9 & 0 & 20 & 30 & 3  \\ 
   \hline
   34 & 32 & 1 & 16 & 8  \\
   \hline
\end{array}

$qdg(3,3) \leq  29$. The $3 \times 3$ queen graph has 28 edges:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   2 & 19 & 5  \\ 
   \hline
   28 & 29 & 13   \\
   \hline
   7 & 0 & 25   \\
   \hline
\end{array}

And for a bit of fun I found that $qdg(4,4) \leq  97$. The $4 \times 4$ queen graph has 76 edges:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
   \hline
   2 & 91 & 23 & 47   \\ 
   \hline
   58 & 97 & 1 & 88    \\
   \hline
   5 & 0 & 72 & 84    \\
   \hline
   78 & 59 & 86 & 36     \\
   \hline
\end{array}