# Minimum length of sequence such that every integer from 1 to n can be achieved as the sum of some contiguous subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

This question literally came to me in a fever dream last night, and it's frustrating me to no end. I'll try to explain it as best I can, but there may not be a satisfying answer; the best outcome might be someone finds something interesting about it.

Define an $n$-*good sequence of length* $k$ as any sequence $A=(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)$ such that for all integers $1\leq m \leq n$, there is some contiguous subsequence of $A$ that sums to $m$; that is, there exist $i\leq j$ such that $$m=\sum_{k=i}^{k=j}a_j.$$

Let $f(n)$ be the minimum $k$ such that there exists an $n$-good sequence of length $k$, and $g(k)$ be the maximum $n$ such that there exists an $n$-good sequence of length $k$.

Questions:

1. Is there any way to efficiently compute $f(n)$ and $g(k)$?
2. Even better, is there a closed formula for $f(n)$ and $g(k)$
3. Is there a way to construct a $g(k)$-good sequence of length $k$? i.e, how can one construct a sequence of length $k$ that attains the most possible consecutive positive integers as sums of its subsequences?

I've tried what are essentially brute-force approaches, but they're very slow. From these, as best as I can tell, $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=3$, $g(3)=6$, $g(4)=9$, $g(5)=13$, and $g(6)=18$, but there could be a problem with my approach.
It's natural that $k\leq g(k) \leq \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, as there are $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ subsequences. Some construction might give better bounds here, but the ultimate goal would be a value, or an algorithm, for $g(k)$.

I'm excited to hear if anybody has any thoughts!

Comment: [Crossposted to mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336383/minimum-length-of-sequence-such-that-every-integer-from-1-to-n-can-be-achieved-a).

Comment: So you are looking for [sparse rulers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_ruler), where the numbers of your sequence are the distances between successive marks on the ruler.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes! This is absolutely it. If anybody is interested, it seems like it's the "incomplete" sparse ruler with $k$ marks. Wow!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279766/sparse-ruler-conjecture